# Center multiple objects by finding offset

Tags: geometry

I'm bad in explanations so i did a little visualization:

[image]

Let's think objects are wagons on this picture. The `C` wagon is always horizontally centered, and always located at the same point. We know its length `Cx`, and it may also have attached wagons. Each attached wagon has known `Wo` offset from `C` wagon center to its center. Wagons count and their length is unknown and may vary on both left/right sides, but the total `Tx` and single side `Lx`/`Rx` length is known, that always include half of `Cx`.

**Issue**: How to find new offset, let's name it `Co`, to add/subtract from `Wo`, including `C`, to horizontally center all wagons.

Probably it's a very easy issue but i can't figure it out myself. Thanks in advance!

**Update.** Solution `Co = 1/2(Lx-Rx)`

Comment: Hmm, so you're looking for a $C_0$ to shift all wagons so they are all centered around $(0,0)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, perhaps we can find the "span" of all wagons, meaning the lefternmost and righternmost points <s>(if those are real words)</s>.

In this case, since $C$ is conveniently in the center, the lefternmost point is $-L_X$ while the righternmost one is $R_X$.

As such, the "center" of all wagons is $\frac12(R_X-L_X)$. Since we want to make that "center" positioned in $(0,0)$, we can add an offset of $\frac12(L_X-R_X)$, which is the value of $C_0$.

Initially forgot to divide the result by $2$, corrected that!

Comment: Sorry i did mistake in the question issue.

Comment: Upd. You were almost correct, `Co = 1/2(Lx-Rx)`

Comment: Nice, that's correct! I forgot to halve it, haha